# Android window-layering in java

Tags: java, android

I am java programmer, but i never put my hand on android before. I just want to clear some basic stuff that the different between programming a window app and a android app.

I know how to programm a window app that has pop up windows inside the app.
for example:

```
MyWindowClass m= new MyWindowClass(new java.awt.Frame(), true);
m.setVisible(true);
```

But i do not know how to open a new view or layer at Android.
Can someone give me some hinds.

Comment: Check out PopupWindow: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Comment: You want a Pop-up window or a pop-up dialog in your application? What purpose will it serve?

Comment: i want a new view in my application. how could i do that.

Comment: Doesn't `Activity` do it? Just override the class and set your `Activity`'s layout (`setContentView`).

Comment: @lucian.pantelimon is that mean i do not have to do anything? it will give me a new view when i press a button?

Comment: yes. it's like a new `Frame`. The only difference is that this new `Frame` is modal (no user interaction with another `Activity` until this one is either finished or sent to the background - i.e. by starting a different `Activity`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to display a pop-up window, just use a `Dialog`.

If you are looking to add an entirely new layer to your application, consider starting a new `Activity` (you can use either `Context.startActivity` or `Context.startActivityForResult` if you are interested in returning a value (placed in a `Bundle`) from that `Activity`.

You can also have another layer by starting a new `Activity` with a transparent background, but there are some limitations when it comes to that such as user input not being passed to the `Activity` behind it.

EDIT:

If you want to have "multiple windows" and not have them lose state (unless they are closed by the system), you can also use `startActivity` with an `Intent` on which you've added the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` flag.

Comment: MyWindowClass m= new MyWindowClass(new java.awt.Frame(), true);
m.setVisible(true);         not something like this?  i don't have to make a new class that that new layer or view?

Comment: The equivalent for `MyWindowClass` would be `MyActivityClass` and you would start it using an `Intent`: `Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivityClass.class); context.startActivity(intent);`.

Comment: Also, `context` must be of type `Context` (an `Activity` extends `Context`). If your context is not an `Activity` you must add a permission to your manifest to allow the application to start new tasks (if I remember correctly - haven't used that yet as I started all my activities from other activities so far). This is better explained here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Comment: Another difference from a `Frame` is that you handle the `Activity` events by overriding functions as opposed to attaching a listener (see the `Activity` lifecycle for events your application will receive and when)